# How to put an incremental counter for each group in SQL (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table - essentially a product and its price between a set of start and end dates. The start and end dates are sorted in ascending order.

```
product start       end         price
A       08/04/2022  12/04/2022  29
A       13/04/2022  12/05/2022  45      
A       13/05/2022  25/12/2022  45
A       26/12/2022  16/05/2023  29
A       17/05/2023  23/05/2023  29
A       24/05/2023  31/12/9999  49
```

What I want is to have a counter that essentially checks if the price has changed from its previous row (for a particular product). If yes, increment the counter by 1, else copy the counter value from above.
Output should look like below:

```
product start       end         price  counter
A       08/04/2022  12/04/2022  29     1
A       13/04/2022  12/05/2022  45     2      
A       13/05/2022  25/12/2022  45     2
A       26/12/2022  16/05/2023  29     3
A       17/05/2023  23/05/2023  29     3
A       24/05/2023  31/12/9999  49     4
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I never used snowflake sql but I think you may try this, do a left join with the same table, but adds an empty row before on the "second table" so then you would have always the next row connected with the previous besides the first row

Comment: This would be way easier to do in the programming language that is requesting this data.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts. However, I have this huge data, and there are multiple joins with other tables (in snowflake) that I need to do. So the preference is to do it in SQL.

Comment: @TimRoberts SQL is probably one of the most underestimated languages - using [windowed function CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76403934/5070879); similar could be achieved with [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize) clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a running sum on a flag that checks if the previous value of the price is not equal to the current price value of a product:

```
with t as
(
  select *,
   case
     when lag(price, 1, price) over (partition by product order by start_dt) <> price
     then 1 else 0
   end as flag
 from tbl
)

select product, start_dt, end_dt, price,
(sum(flag) over (partition by product order by start_dt) + 1) counter
from t
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AMOv2C-R) (on SQL server)

Comment: I renamed `start` to *start_dt* and `end` to *end_dt*.

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake supports [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event) windowed function that is exactly designed for it:

> **Returns a window event number for each row within a window partition when the value of the argument expr1 in the current row is different from the value of expr1 in the previous row.** The window event number starts from 0 and is incremented by 1 to indicate the number of changes so far within that window.

---

```
SELECT *, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(price) 
          OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY start_) + 1 AS counter
FROM tab
ORDER BY product, start_;
```

For input table:

```
ALTER SESSION SET DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(product TEXT, start_ DATE, end_ DATE, price INT)
AS
SELECT 'A','08/04/2022','12/04/2022', 29 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','13/04/2022','12/05/2022', 45 UNION ALL      
SELECT 'A','13/05/2022','25/12/2022', 45 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','26/12/2022','16/05/2023', 29 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','17/05/2023','23/05/2023', 29 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','24/05/2023','31/12/9999', 49;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank() over`.

```
select *, rank() over(order by price) counter
from mytable
```

`rank() over` - this window clause will start from 1, and if the next value is same, then it will continue and not add 1 to the rank value.

So, counter values will be 1,2,2,3,4 because 2nd and 3rd values are same.

Comment: Thanks. However, after running I don't get the desired output. I get:
1,4,4,1,1,6 respectively for each row. Pls note that 29 occurs in 2 sets - once in row 1 and then other time in rows 4,5. They should not be mixed into one group.

Comment: i understand. Then there must be some order in which you want to compare. is it date?

Comment: Yes. Dates (start and end) are sorted in ascending order.

Comment: I think then you need to use `lag()` like above answer.